# Beamer: Generating references w/ A4 page style

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, pagestyle

I have a beamer presentation w/ some citings, and references I want to put at its end. However, there's no room for the references on one slide (and it's difficult to split them like I want, although I may have a separate question about this), so I just want to add a link to an online pdf w/ references. Which brings us to the problem:

(0) What's the easiest way to *generate* regular A4 page(s) of references from or inside a beamer presentation? The presentation and A4 page styles are obviously totally different, and

(1) I don't want to create the references manually (i.e. pick out all occurrences of `\cite{...}` from my presentation, put them into a different document and compile this)

(2) I don't want the references page(s) to appear in my slideshow

Is there a solution to (0) that complies w/ both (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 2):

Following section "21.2  Creating Handouts Using the Article Mode"  starting on page 209 of the [`beamer` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer), you can create the following three separate files:

1: **main.tex**

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
    Author = {Author, A. and Author, B.},
    Title = {Title of the Book},
    Year = {1234}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\mode<presentation>{
\begin{frame}
Some text\cite{key}
\end{frame}
}
\mode<article>{\printbibliography}

\end{document}
```

Where `\mode<presentation>{...}` is used to make sure that the frames are only shown in the presenation, while `\mode<article>{\printbibliography}` only prints the list of references in the associated `article` (A4 document).

2: **main.beamer.tex**

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\input{main.tex}
```

This file will print your presentation:

[image]

3: **main.article.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\setjobnamebeamerversion{main.beamer}
\input{main.tex}
```

This will print the associated list of references:

[image]

Comment: I believe you but can't confirm this. I tried your code and got "Cannot find biblatex.sty". After installing this, it wanted logreq. After installing this, it crashed w/ a host of errors

Comment: @jaam: This is indeed hard to confirm. How did you install the package? Manually yor via some sort of package manager?

Comment: @leadriis Manually (dl-ed the file and copied to a suitable location)

Comment: @jaam: Since some package depend on others it is often not the best idea to manally "install"  packages. Depending on your distribution there might be an udate / package manager that you could use instead.

Comment: I've installed them w/ `apt` and all my tex packages are up to date. I'm on Xubuntu

Comment: @jaam: Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in solving problems related to installation. Your chances of recieving a useful answer might be higer if you asked a follow up question on that topic. You might also want to check if [this MWE for biblatex](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/134144)  works.

Comment: I don't think it worked _correctly_. It compiled and all but the pdf had no bibliography. This is different what I had earlier w/ your MWE. When I tried your MWE now, it also compiled w/out errors but didn't produce a pdf. Sth's definitely wrong and I'd like to know what `apt` package I should install to get biblatex. Maybe it would work then. Is there a way to use `\addbibresource` w/ bibtex? bibtex has always worked for me

Comment: @jaam: `\addbibresource` is a `biblatex` command and will not work with `bibtex`. I also tried modifying my answer to use `bibtex` instead, but I wan unfortunately not able to get it to work.

Comment: I still think that asking a follow up question regarding your general `biblatex` problem would be best. Maybe you can come back to this question when `biblatex` and `biber` are properly installed and work as expected.